# How not to send ANY query parameter facebook pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-pixel

I need some help with Facebook pixel.

I have a pixel installed on my web:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document ,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '123123123123123');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
console.log(fbq)
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=123123123123123&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

And I would like to know how to make it **NOT** send query parameters to the events, is this possible?

Events manager:

[image]

What I'm looking for:

URL: https://example.com   --- **no query params**

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any update on this?